# MacBook Pro 16" 2019 Intel kernel panic

Tags: macbook-pro, sleep-wake, kernel-panic

I'm having this kernel panic... I don't know what is related to, I had another kernel panic related to Intel's HAXM program to run Android emulators but I uninstalled it and after a while, this kernel panic showed up. The panic happened when the mac was asleep, it never panicked when it is awake and I'm using it, just when it goes to sleep and sometimes, not always.

```
panic(cpu 1 caller 0xfffffff00dd3a024): macOS panic detected
Debugger message: panic
Memory ID: 0x6
OS release type: User
OS version: 19P549
macOS version: 21A559
Kernel version: Darwin Kernel Version 21.1.0: Wed Oct 13 18:09:06 PDT 2021; root:xnu-8019.41.5~2/RELEASE_ARM64_T8010
Kernel UUID: 5206FA9B-BD6D-381D-A198-5F6E6A09B67F
iBoot version: iBoot-7429.41.4
secure boot?: YES
x86 EFI Boot State: 0x16
x86 System State: 0x0
x86 Power State: 0x0
x86 Shutdown Cause: 0x5
x86 Previous Power Transitions: 0x10001000100
PCIeUp link state: 0x36894700
Paniclog version: 13
Kernel slide:      0x0000000005cac000
Kernel text base:  0xfffffff00ccb0000
mach_absolute_time: 0x1a0b37c0978
Epoch Time:        sec       usec
  Boot    : 0x628538f2 0x000d0253
  Sleep   : 0x62879017 0x000d5999
  Wake    : 0x62879145 0x000d9afe
  Calendar: 0x6287bdc2 0x000d4e6e

Zone info:
Foreign   : 0xfffffff0581b4000 - 0xfffffff0581c4000
Native    : 0xffffffe0006a0000 - 0xffffffe6006a0000
Readonly  : 0 - 0
Metadata  : 0xffffffeb00ab0000 - 0xffffffeb04c10000
Bitmaps   : 0xffffffeb022b0000 - 0xffffffeb0250c000
CORE 0: PC=0xfffffff00da3f13c, LR=0xfffffff00da41cf4, FP=0xffffffeb0410b910
CORE 1 is the one that panicked. Check the full backtrace for details.
Panicked task 0xffffffe0f2f50658: 0 pages, 230 threads: pid 0: kernel_task
Panicked thread: 0xffffffe0f38fc000, backtrace: 0xffffffeb04bdb670, tid: 443
          lr: 0xfffffff00d497388  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb6b0
          lr: 0xfffffff00d497118  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb720
          lr: 0xfffffff00d5cfeac  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb7a0
          lr: 0xfffffff00d5cf03c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb850
          lr: 0xfffffff00daf95fc  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdb860
          lr: 0xfffffff00d496e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbbf0
          lr: 0xfffffff00d496e2c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbc50
          lr: 0xfffffff00e5eb488  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbc70
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd3a024  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbca0
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd26f5c  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbd00
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd2d410  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbd50
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd28e48  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbdf0
          lr: 0xfffffff00dd26640  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbe70
          lr: 0xfffffff00dbd8db4  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbea0
          lr: 0xfffffff00da3f3a4  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbee0
          lr: 0xfffffff00da3ebb4  fp: 0xffffffeb04bdbf20
          lr: 0xfffffff00db045a0  fp: 0x0000000000000000
```

Comment: What model is the MacBook? Mine has had similar issues and, after taking it to a Genius Bar, I determined it was a hardware issue and a costly fix. Personally I'd recommend buying an M1. If that's not in the cards, get the computer fixed by Apple.

Comment: MacBook Pro 16" 2019... I'm in Argentina, it's hard to get an Apple MacBook Pro repaired here. Any way to determine if this is a hardware or software issue?

Comment: Try backing up your system, wiping the Mac, and reinstalling a fresh copy of MacOS from the internet. Then put ONLY YOUR FILES back onto the computer, and install each application, program, etc from the internet, fresh copies. If it continues to happen, it's a hardware issue - replacing all the software will ensure that the software is not to blame. (If it starts panicking suddenly after a certain program is installed, then that program is to blame.) If it doesn't happen anymore, then it was a software issue.

Comment: Try the MacBook's built in diagnostics to see if that finds anything - it didn't on mine, but it could on yours. [Instructions on diagnostics here.](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731)